# How to Access Members in a Linked List Inside a Linked List

Tags: c++, class, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I need to access members of a linked list class inside of a linked list. I can manage my `Artist` list okay, but cannot set `int x` in my `SongList` class. I've tried setting it with `*(temp->songHead).x = 5;`, `*temp->songHead.x = 5;`, `*(temp->songHead)->x = 5;`, and `*temp->songHead->x = 5;`.

When I compile it, I get the error:

> invalid use of incomplete type 'struct songList'

How can I set int x?

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST
#define LINKED_LIST
class SongList{
    public:
        SongList();
        int x;
        void add(int x);
    private:
        struct Song{
            char *name;
            int minutes;
            int seconds;
            int views;
            int likes;
            Song *next;
        };
        Song *head;
};

class LinkedList{
    public:
        LinkedList();
        ~LinkedList();

        void test(int x);
        void add(char ch);
        bool find(char ch);
        bool del(char ch);
        void list();

    private:
        struct Artist{
            char character;
            Artist *next;
            struct songList *songHead;
            SongList ptr;
        };
        Artist *head;
};
#endif
```

```
// Code to set int x
void LinkedList::test(int x){
    struct Artist *temp;
    temp = head;
    *(temp->songHead).x = 5;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using manual linked lists instead of using `std::list`? Where is the code that populates the lists? In `test()`, assuming the `songList` is not empty (which you don't check for), you don't need to use `operator*` to access `x`, you can use `operator->` instead: `head->songHead->x = 5;`

Comment: `struct songList *songHead;` There is no `songList` Do you mean `SongList`?

Comment: It's a school assignment, and I know the class is present b/c I tested for it in the constructor, I'm not testing for any present nodes, but I shouldn't need any to set int x.

Comment: Remove `struct` from your variable declarations, it's unnecessary in c++ and is hiding the cause of your issue

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't require you to add `struct` in front of declarations of variables containing `struct`s. Adding it allows you to use undefined types in your variable declarations.

If you remove `struct` you'll quickly see the true cause of your error:

```
songList *songHead;
```

Will give an error something like this (this is from clang, other compilers may not be as helpful):

> error: unknown type name 'songList'; did you mean 'SongList'?

Your access to `songHead` is also incorrect:

```
*(temp->songHead).x = 5;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
*(temp->songHead.x) = 5;
```

What you actually want is:

```
(*temp->songHead).x = 5;
```

Or more simply:

```
temp->songHead->x = 5;
```